# Two small number subtract get zero in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I am writing a fortran code, which works with high precision. Here I am trying to use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV to achieve that. I find out that if I subtract two small number, the answer I get will be zero. But if I add them it would be fine.

Here is my program:

```
program test

  USE ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, ONLY : REAL32

  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL(REAL32), PARAMETER :: RE_L=-1.7499576837060936950743114606, &
                            RE_R=-1.7499576837060933110499019727
  REAL(REAL32) :: A 

  A=(RE_R)-(RE_L)
  PRINT 20, A
  20 FORMAT(f50.40)


end program test
```

The result I got is 0.00000000000000000000000000000. And I do not know why.

Comment: We have many related questions asked already, I suggest readimg them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016261/precision-problems-of-real-numbers-in-fortran https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052886/fortran-floating-point-equality https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715548/assigning-a-lower-precision-number-to-a-higher-precision-in-fortran90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are bumping into Single Precision significant digits in the literals, and in the REAL32 range.

Bump to REAL64, add a double specifier on the literals `1.7499576837060933110499019727d+0`

```
prompt$ gfortran toosmallorg.f90
prompt$ ./a.out
        0.0000000000000004440892098500626161694527
```

Even with REAL64 d literals, you only get 16 digits after the decimal point, and the displayed result is wrong.  With REAL32 only 7 digits after the decimal are recognized (under the default settings this Fedora machine has with gfortran 7.3).  REAL128 might give enough wiggle room with the literals.

*Fair warning; Not an expert regarding Fortran or the numeric precisions allowed*

Comment: Right! Now I got the result! Thank you!

Comment: By the way, so d is a double specifier, what about f? It cannot be taken as a specifier?

Comment: @ShiqiHe, for floating point literals, the two types of Exponent literals are E for single, D for double.  In the above `d+0` means treat as double precision but don't shift the magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long story, you can search google for some key works like "
What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic", some very good relevant pages would show up.

In short, float point format, float or double, can only represent the number up to certain precision. The algorithm should be carefully designed in certain cases to get reasonable accuracy, for example, the minimum float point x that makes (1.0+x)-1.0!=0.0 is defined as FLT_EPSILON, it's value is surprisingly large than you may expected.

Comment: There is no FLT_EPSILON in Fortran and no `!=` in Fortran. And the book is What should every Computer scientist ... and I recommend it *only* to real computer scientists. It is *way* to advanced for an average programmer like me, especialy if they suppose I should really  *know* all that stuff by heart.

Comment: no matter how many digits fortran print out, only about the first 7 digits in 1.234567Exx is valid for float, all other value is not accurate. you can try that there is no single float point number between 1.0 and 1.0000001192092895507812500000000000000000.