# How to write MATLAB variable into text file with format like 3.4d3

Tags: matlab, fortran

I want to read MATLAB output by Fortran code.
Therefore, I need to write MATLAB script to generate a text file with decimal notation.
like: MATLAB code

```
x=123.45
 fprintf(filetxt,'%f',x)
```

Output:

```
123.45
```

How to write output command or set format so I get this value in filetxt like:

```
1.2345d02
```

Maximum I can get is 1.2345e02 but I want to write like 1.2345d02

Comment: _Why_ do you want to write like `1.2345d02`?  I suspect your Fortran program won't care.

Comment: I read fortran manual where it say we need to write float with 'd' so otherwise fortran compiler with roud off it to a single percision during reading file and assigning to variable.even if variable if declared double percision. i think my understanding must be wrong as you said.

Comment: That's true only for constants in source files.  For input at run time the answer below covers things.  See also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33319357/3157076).

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by @francescalus, I think your Fortran compiler will probably read in a floating-point literal like `1.2345e02` as expected into a double-precision variable (as in the code below). So, I guess you can just write `1.2345e02` rather than `1.2345d02` to a data file...

```
program main
    implicit none
    real :: xs
    double precision :: xd

    open(10, file='test.dat', status='old')
    read(10,*) xs
    read(10,*) xd
    close(10)

    print "(a, e30.18)", "xs = ", xs
    print "(a, e30.18)", "xd = ", xd
end
```

test.dat:

```
0.1234567890123456e12
0.1234567890123456e12
```

Result (gfortran test.f90):

```
xs =       0.123456790528000000E+12
xd =       0.123456789012345596E+12  <-- double-precision accuracy
```

Comment: Perhaps the important part is "An exponent containing a D is processed identically to an exponent containing an E."  That's F77.

Comment: Thanks very much for your info, now I've changed the phrase to "your Fortran compiler...". (And, apart from OP's question, it is interesting why the "D" exponent is used in a file. I will ask somewhere later.)